# How to find $P(A \cap B')$ and $P(A' \cap B')$ given $P(A)$, $P(B)$, and $P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

I'm having issues with this.

Given $P(A) = 0.59$, $P(B) = 0.30$, $P(A \cap B)  = 0.21$,

Find $P(A \cap B')$ and $P(A' \cap B')$.

Thanks.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: And work from the inside out to assign probabilities to regions of your Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

$P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B')$

$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$